# Using Nexmo API behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, sms, vonage

Currently I used Nexmo API for my SMS authentication but encountered problem because of the ConnectionTimeOut Exception.

**Note:**
 1. I'm using a corporate proxy
 2. Laravel 5.4

Does anyone here give me ideas how to configure nexmo to use proxy?